# Looping through and comparing a vector and a data frame (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

what i'm trying to do is compare the vector below (called instru) with two columns from a data frame called train, if that row matches something from the vector then put 1 else put 0. I've put my code below but currently it doesn't work and gives me 0 in every file.

I've managed to get the code to create 18 different csv's (one for each instrument) with the 1 or the 0 (on the new instrument column) on each row on if its equal vector but currently it just returns incorrect values in the new column.
for example:
If I was to load
the file titled Clarinet (each instrument needs to have its own file):

```
 Mix1_instrument | Mix2_instrument     | instrument name
    ------------------------------------------------
    Clarinet        |   French horn    |   1

    Flute              |    French horn | 0

    Accordian        |   Clarinet       |   1

    Flute              |    French horn | 0

      Clarinet        |   Trumpet   | 1
```

my current code looks like this:

```
   instru = c("Accordian", "Clarinet", "Trumpet", "DoubleBass", "Oboe", "Piano", "Saxophone", "Violin", "Cello", "Tuba", "Viola",
                    "Bassoon", "EnglishHorn", "French horn", "Flute", "Piccolo", "SynthBass", "Trombone")
    
    
    for (instruments in instru) {
      
      if (train$mix1_instrument %in% instruments || train$mix2_instrument %in% instruments) {
        
        train$instruments <- c("1")
        
      } else {
        train$instruments <- c("0")
      }
      
      write.table(train, file = paste0("C:\\Users\\my-PC\\Dropbox\\Year_Three\\Data mining\\Cleaned_data\\output\\", instruments, ".csv"), sep = ",")
                  
    train [instruments] <- NULL 
    
    }
```

train dataframe looks like this:

```
        Mix1_instrument | Mix2_instrument
        ------------------------------------------------
        Clarinet        |   French horn
        
        Flute              |    French horn
        
        Clarinet        |   French horn

           English Horn  |   Flute
```

Comment: can you provide an example of `train$mix1_instrument`. Just from eyballing your code I think you need `grepl()` instead of `%in%` then you can also get rid of the `if` conditions. But hard to assess without knowing what's in `train$mix1_instrument`. You could try `dput()`.

Comment: sorry yeah i'll add it now :)

Comment: Just edit your code and provide an example data.frame

Comment: just added it to the bottom

Comment: FYI: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can leave out the for loop, as R works vector-safe on your list of instruments. Using `tidyverse` your code could look like this:

```
# load tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# set vector of instruments
instru = c("Accordian", "Clarinet", "Trumpet", "DoubleBass", "Oboe", "Piano", "Saxophone", "Violin", "Cello", "Tuba", "Viola", "Bassoon", "EnglishHorn", "French horn", "Flute", "Piccolo", "SynthBass", "Trombone")

# create dummy train data.frame (more exactly a "tibble")
train <- tibble(mix1_instrument = c("a", "b", "Clarinet"),
                mix2_instrument = c("a", "Clarinet", "c"),
                xxx = c("Clarinet", "b", "c"))

#> train
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#mix1_instrument mix2_instrument xxx     
#<chr>           <chr>           <chr>   
#1 a               a               Clarinet
#2 b               Clarinet        b       
#3 Clarinet        c               c       


# add column "instruments" to train
train <- train %>% 
  mutate(instruments = case_when(
    mix1_instrument %in% instru ~ "1",
    mix2_instrument %in% instru ~ "1",
    TRUE ~"0"
  ))

#>     train
## A tibble: 3 x 4
# mix1_instrument mix2_instrument xxx      instruments
# <chr>           <chr>           <chr>    <chr>      
#1 a               a               Clarinet 0          
#2 b               Clarinet        b        1          
#3 Clarinet        c               c        1
```

Comment: well, this will not scale very easily If you had, say, 100 columns

Comment: You're right, Sotos. But I didn't understand that scalability was a requirement. Was it?

Comment: It always is. We never overfit answers to the questions. We make them as generalized as possible since other people (which might have more columns in their datasets) will go over this answer to solve the same problem.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help but how would i run this against the 18 different instruments, I've added some extra detail to my question above to help. thanks in advance :)

Comment: I assume you don't need an answer anymore as you removed your question. Or was this a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with `dplyr`, you can do this with mutate.

```
instru = c("Accordian", "Clarinet", "Trumpet", "DoubleBass", "Oboe", "Piano", "Saxophone", "Violin", "Cello", "Tuba", "Viola",
           "Bassoon", "EnglishHorn", "French horn", "Flute", "Piccolo", "SynthBass", "Trombone")

mix1_instruments = c("Accordion", "Trumpet", "Violin", "Cello", "Triangle")
mix2_instruments = c("Bassoon", "Saxophone", "Flute", "French horn", "Washboard")

train = data.frame(mix1_instruments, mix2_instruments)

train <- train %>%
  mutate(instruments = (mix1_instruments %in% instru) | (mix2_instruments %in% instru))
```

The outputs are `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but they can be converted to 0 or 1 as well.

```
train$instruments <- as.numeric(train$instruments)
```

Edit: Just saw I got scooped while writing my response (by a far better one!) but that there's a scalability issue.

The following will insert new columns with the name `<old_column_name>_instruments` with logicals for if each entry in that column are in instru, then consolodiate them into a single column containing a logical for if any value in *any* column contained an entry in instru:

```
instru = c("Accordian", "Clarinet", "Trumpet", "DoubleBass", "Oboe", "Piano", "Saxophone", "Violin", "Cello", "Tuba", "Viola",
           "Bassoon", "EnglishHorn", "French horn", "Flute", "Piccolo", "SynthBass", "Trombone")

mix1_instruments = c("Clarinet", "Flute", "Clarinet", "English Horn", "Washboard", "Saxophone", "Washboard")
mix2_instruments = c("French Horn", "French Horn", "French Horn", "Flute", "Flute", "Triangle", "Triangle")

train = data.frame(mix1_instruments, mix2_instruments)

train %<>%
  mutate_all(funs(instruments = . %in% instru)) %>%
  unite(col = instruments,
        ends_with('_instruments_instruments'), # optional, iterates only over columns added by unite in this particular dataset
        remove=T) %>%
  mutate(instruments = as.numeric(grepl('TRUE', instruments)))
```

Output:

```
train
#  mix1_instruments mix2_instruments instruments
#1         Clarinet      French Horn           1
#2            Flute      French Horn           1
#3         Clarinet      French Horn           1
#4     English Horn            Flute           1
#5        Washboard            Flute           1
#6        Saxophone         Triangle           1
#7        Washboard         Triangle           0
```

Note: the `%<>%` is from `magrittr` and simply replaces the `x <- x %>% ...` syntax

You can [output a dataframe with the write.x functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html), to output as a csv:

```
write.csv(train, "/path/to/dir/filename.csv", row.names=F)
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your help but I can't seem to see how would i get this to write to the csv files? I've added some extra detail to my question above. thanks in advance :)

Comment: I included a bit at the end on writing dataframes to files